# How can I list all accessed files on process startup

Tags: linux, filesystems, lsof

I have a process that fails on startup due to some permission issues. I want to check what files it tries to open on startup but with `lsof` I can list only opened files for a running process but what can I do when it fails to start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start process by hand, and use **strace** to know what files it tried to open:

```
strace -f -e trace=open -o process.trace <command to start process>
```

Then manipulate file **process.trace** to determine what you want.

Comment: Ou, sorry I didn't mention I'm using OS X but you gave a good hint and I found `dtruss` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925978/equivalent-of-strace-feopen-command-on-mac-os-x